# Objective C / php session?

Tags: php, ios, session

The user inputs their username and password to log in the first time. If success i create a php session
On subsequent requests,the php session is lost, so how should I send the username/pass again?
Can I have our server send a cookie to the app and have the app send it back using NSURLConnection or something?

Is it possible to provide a simple example?

Thanks

Comment: Because sessions work by cookies, then yes, you'd need to send the session cookie that PHP automatically sets back in order to use that session.  I know nothing about Obj-C, otherwise I'd give you a brief example.

Comment: You could also capture the session ID and pass it to the PHP script through a POST or GET parameter using the name PHPSESSID.  You'll have to make sure that `session.use_only_cookies` is off though.

Comment: Turning off cookie-only sessions [can lead to a huge security problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) -- *don't*.

Comment: Thanks for help, i notice that if i run the scripts in my server session works prety well, but from the app within iphone it doesn't. Using example.com?something&somerhingelse does work using $_get, but this is not secure, write?

Answer (score 0):

How about storing username and password on the device and then automatically logging in when the app is started in the future? That can easily be done using NSUserDefaults.

```
// SET
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"MyUsername" forKey:@"username"];

// GET
NSString *strUsername = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username"];
```

Sorry if I didn't understand the question.

Comment: hello, thanks for reply. can you please develop this just a little more? Do you suggest that on every server request i do login avoiding sessions? I mean, I'm using uiwebview to load a php file from my webserver. i loose the username and password after receiving first php data. so I need to have a way of make objective c load another file and use this username and password to match the php session. This is my first experience with ios, so i really need help. thanks